# variables as columns in a Table Variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to pass variables as columns in a Table Variable.

```
DECLARE @VAR1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @VAR2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

and I have set values in these variables. Now I want to form a table from these results.

This is what I have tried

```
DECLARE @Query TABLE(@Pvar1,@Total)
```

Desired output:

```
Var1   Var2

 abc    xyz
```

Comment: Do you want to use the variables to determine the field type or content?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server you cant declare a table variable with other variables, you have to use the same datatype

```
DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'abc'
DECLARE @var2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'xyz'

DECLARE @table TABLE(
   var1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
   var2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @table SELECT @var1, @var2

SELECT * FROM @table
```